# How can I fix 'register_blueprint' error when using Flask and Flask-Admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I've had no problem setting-up my app with Celery, login manager etc. this way, but Flask-Admin is breaking...

```
from flask_admin import Admin

admin = Admin(name='myapp')

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config['dev'])
    config['dev'].init_app(app)
    ...
    admin.init_app(admin)
    ...
    return app
```

When I try and run Flask, I get the following error before any blueprints are even registered...

```
  File "c:\mtrapp\venv\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\base.py", line 697, in init_app
    app.register_blueprint(view.create_blueprint(self))
AttributeError: 'Admin' object has no attribute 'register_blueprint'
```

Where am I doing this wrong? Thanks!

Comment: did you check `flask_admin` documentation and examples? it should be rather: first `app = Flask(...)` , next `admin = Admin(app, ...)`

Comment: I am using an application factory, the example documentation is not.

Comment: or maybe you have to use `app` in `admin.init_app(app)`.

Comment: Thanks @furas... you were right. I can't believe I was glossing over such an obvious error. Thank you!